# Accessing all shared objects AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Is there any way to find out all the shared objects that are accessed by a SWF file?

I am working on some decompiled source of a Flash chatroom. Trying to edit the KICKBAN command which is accessed by the SWF file, but I can't find its function in the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Every shared object is stored as file on your personal computer.
For example, on Windows 8.1 path looks like:

`c:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\`

If your application works, you will be able to find corresponding .so files. You can delete them, for debugging purposes, you can read them. If you want learn content of `.so` files, you can use [AIR application](http://blog.coursevector.com/minerva).

Comment: Yeah i know about that but i didn't find the file i am searching for, Is there any possible way to get all the REMOTE SHARED OBJECTS from FMS ?